# Google App Engine - ways of doing php includes in java?

Tags: java, php, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin

I am looking to use php includes for my header, nav, footer etc. Was wondering what the best method is and how to implement?

I've heard of using compatible jars. Would this suffice? If so how would I implement.

I am using java eclipse on a mac.

Thanks in advance.
Scott

Comment: You can run PHP code with a java program: http://quercus.caucho.com/

Answer (score 1):

You [can't use PHP](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=13&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log) on Google App Engine, so you will have to rely on Django or Jinja2 or another framework for your templates.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [JSP includes](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/syntax/1.2/syntaxref1214.html) instead:

```jsp
<jsp:include page="{relativeURL | <%= expression %>}" flush="true| false" />
```